# Correlated query in criteria Builder Hibernate 5

Tags: hibernate, criteria-api, correlated-subquery

I want to fetch only those columns which have the latest version of a **content**

Content entity has ContentPK as Primary key(id, version)
Along the lines of a native correlation query like
`select * from content c1 where content.version = (select max(version) from content c2 where c2.id=c1.id)`

I want to achieve this using CriteriaBuilder

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = currentSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Content> parentQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Content.class);
        Root<Content> root = parentQuery.from(Content.class);
        parentQuery.select(root);
        Subquery<Integer> subquery = parentQuery.subquery(Integer.class);
        Root<Content> subRoot = subquery.correlate(root);
        subquery.select(criteriaBuilder.max(subRoot.get(Content_.contentPK).get(ContentPK_.version)));
        subquery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(subRoot.get(Content_.contentPK).get(ContentPK_.id), root.get(Content_.contentPK).get(ContentPK_.id)));
        parentQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(Content_.contentPK).get(ContentPK_.version), subquery));
        return currentSession().createQuery(parentQuery).list();
```

Gives this error

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: select generatedAlias0 from com.m3.db.content.Content as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.contentPK.version=(select max(generatedAlias0.contentPK.version) from  where generatedAlias0.contentPK.id=generatedAlias0.contentPK.id)]

How to fix this error?

Comment: I guess `version` is key word. so try change it to other else.

Comment: No, its a Content class property. A content version is incremented when it is edited.

Comment: How did you solve it?